# “Given an array A consisting of n integers and an integer b, find out if there exists two elements c and d in A, such that c+d=b"

Tags: algorithm

develop and implement an algorithm for array  for the given problem
“Given an array A consisting of n integers and an integer b, find out if there exists two elements c and d in A, such that c+d=b"

you algorithm should not run more than Θ(n log n)time

Comment: *"develop and implement"*: that is indeed what you should do. Let is know when you bump into a specific problem.

Answer (score -1):

A brute-force solution is to loop through c and loop through d and test whether c+d=b. However, the time complexity is $O(n^2)$.

Think another way, as it only requires check the existence of such a pair, the problem can be converted to a search problem, i.e. given c and b, whether in the array, there is an element equals to d. And the binary search yields time complexity in $O(log n)$, thus deserves a try.

Algo

1. sort the array (in $O(nlog n)$);
2. loop through c, and find whether there left an element equals b-c in the array except for c. Binary search in a sorted array yields time complexity $O(log n)$. And loop through c factor it by $n$. Thus the time complexity this step is $O(nlog n)$.

And the total time complexity is $O(nlog n)$.

Comment: The searching part can be reduced to `O(n)` using two pointers, although the total complexity will still be `O(n log n)` due to the sorting.

Comment: @FeiXiang Thank you for the comment. Would you mind a little more details? Would like to know.

Comment: Look it up. This problem is often used as an example for the two pointers technique, so there's plenty of good explanations out there.